# Themes don't show in tweak manager

Tags: icon-themes

I downloaded a few themes, extracted the tar balls and copied the folders to both `~/themes` and `/usr/share/themes`, but they still don't show up in gnome tweak manager. What should I do?

Comment: It's not ~/themes but ~/.themes, also what themes and what ubuntu release?

Answer (score 0):

found the problem icon pack should go to /usr/share/icons !